# bootstrap row 100% width without horizontal scroll and adaptive on each size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

Hey guys I am trying to add a container on which I have a row and a column but with full width.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <h4>This is a heading</h4>
    <span>This is a span</span>
    </div>
    </div>
</div> 

.row{
  background: orange;
  margin: 0 -50px;
  padding: 0 50px;
}
```

I've got a solution like above one but the problem with that is in different resolution a horizontal scroll aper and also sometimes the margins are visible.

This structure is mandatory so I cannot modify the html structure just need a css solution.

**[fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/82025/)**

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
    @media (min-width: 768px)
      .container {
         max-width: 100%;
    }
```

This will overwrite the original max-width that is now in play. Just to be sure, you can put there the same css code without the media query, so it will work on all screen resolutions.

Answer (score 3):

Always use a stable version of boostrap. You are at present using 3.0.0 version, which is not a supported version by boostrap.

Try using bootstrap version 3.3.7 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/)

It provides a `container-fluid` class, that takes full 100% width

```css
.row {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h4>This is a heading</h4>
      <span>This is a span</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S.: the latest version of bootstrap is [4.1.x](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)